# Error after importing database using phpmyadmin: Undefined property: PDO::$connect_error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

1. I used scp to copy my scripts from a remote server to my localhost.
2. Then I used the export and import functions in phpmyadmin to copy the database to my localhost.
3. When entering the websites in my localhost, I get the exact same output, but with an error message on the line after include('config.php') --> "Undefined property: PDO::$connect_error"

I changed the username and password in the localhost config.php file, because I use different login information on my local phpmyadmin.
Other than that they are exactly the same files.

My config.php file:

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO(
                'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase;charset=utf8',
                'root',
                'pw123',
                array(
                        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false
                )
        );

?>
```

Can someone explain what may cause the error message?

---

**This worked for me:**

My first lines in index.php:

```
// Check connection
if ($dbh->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $dbh->connect_error);
}
include('header.php');
```

My first two lines in my header.php:

```
error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE );
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

**Solution:**
When I copied those two lines into my index.php script, the error message disappeared.
Please explain to us if somebody knows why.

Comment: Did you try to `try{ ...your code... } catch(Exception $ex) { echo $ex->getMessage(); }` ?

Comment: Can you add the the code for the other php script to your question?

Comment: This worked:
My first lines in index.php:

// Check connection
if ($dbh->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $dbh->connect_error);
}
//echo "Connected successfully";

The first two lines in my include('header.php'):

error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE );
ini_set('display_errors', true);

When i copied those two lines into my index.php script, the error message dissapeared.

Comment: what you did is just buried your head in the sand. the error is still there but you made it silent. VERY unwise

Answer (score 1):

> Undefined property: PDO::$connect_error

If you check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php), you'll see that the PDO instance does not have public properties at all. And unlike mysqli, PDO will always throw an exception for a connection error.

tl;dr - remove that condition completely and don't just hide the error message